# the greater of two random variables

Tags: probability, normed-spaces, random

For two independent normal random variables with non-zero mean

$$ X \sim N(u_1,\sigma_1)  ,   Y \sim N(u_2,\sigma_2)  $$

If we have the condition, $$E(X^2 ) > E(Y^2)$$

is this condition always true?
$$E(\sqrt{X^2}) > E(\sqrt{Y^2}) $$

Comment: A normally distributed random variable has a non-zero probability to be negative, so how do you define $\sqrt{X}$?

Comment: The question might be better phrased in terms of conditional probability, something like "If $E(X|X>0)>E(Y|Y>0)$ then does the statement having squareroots on the $X,Y$ (to the left of the condition symbols) then follow?"

Comment: Choose *non-equal* $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i>0$ so that $E(X|X>0)=E(Y|Y>0)$. It's clear that $E(\sqrt X|X>0)\ne E(\sqrt Y|Y>0)$ in general and hence by continuity the condition listed is not always true.

Comment: Thank you for comments everyone. I changed the question.

Comment: Dpestar-- Good, now the question makes sense. (Upvote on question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a normal variable $N(\mu,\sigma)$ where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation and so $\sigma^2$ is the variance, from the formula $V(X)=E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$ one can get $E(X^2)=\mu^2+\sigma^2.$

Now let $X=N(2,1.5)$ and $Y=N(\sqrt{5},1)$ so that $E(X^2)=6.25,\ E(Y^2)=6.$ 
Then we have here $E(X^2)>E(Y^2).$ But in comparing the two expected values of the absolute values, which as far as I know means doing integrals numerically, we get $E(|X|)\approx 2.12718$ and $E(|Y|) \approx 2.24488.$ That is, the expected values of the absolute values are in reverse order from the expected values of the squares in this case. [The post refers to expected values of $\sqrt(X^2),$ however for real $a$ one has $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ so it doesn't change things to use absolute values here.]

Comment: May i have one more question? How did you calculate numerically? I've refered "A.M.Mathai, Quadratic form of random variables" to calculate the fractional moment, but are there any other equation to solve it?

Comment: @Dpestar I have a calculator which implements a subset of maple. When given a definite integral which it cannot find "exactly" it goes into a subroutine for numerical integration. The topic of numerical integration in general is a bit involved, and I admit I don't know which routine my calculator goes into.